# Translating bash to python, finding position of "^$" characters in a file content

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to transform a bash script to python, and I have a piece of code that I want to understands better. The script:

```
checkzero()
{
    dd < "$1" bs=1 skip="$2" count=1 2> /dev/null | \
        LANG=C grep -q -z '^$'
}
while true; do
            if checkzero "$initramfs" $end; then
                end=$((end + 4))
                while checkzero "$initramfs" $end; do
                    end=$((end + 4))
                done
                break
            fi
....
```

My understanding is that a file is verified byte by byte to find a specific character and if it finds the character stops.

```
with open("initramfs", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != "":
        byte = f.read(1)
```

My issues is to traslate this part `grep -q -z '^$'` . How do I translate the '^$' in python.

Comment: `^$` is a regular expression that means "the start-of-line marker followed by the end-of-line marker" -- i.e. an empty line. Together with the `-z` option (which makes grep use `\0` instead of `\n` for line endings), that checkzero function returns "true" if the dd output either starts with a null byte, or contains 2 consecutive null bytes.

Comment: I would go with `[[ $(dd .... | xxd -p) == 00 ]]`

Comment: `^$` is two characters used by regular expressions. `^` is the start of a line and '$' is the end. You can also use regular expression in Python with `re` library or you can look for the  newline character which is `\n`.

Comment: @KamilCuk - I don't want to change the bash I want to recreate the functionality in python.

Comment: @BenoitZu I know that ^ represent the start and $ the end in a regular expression, my question is how I check for it in the byte content, represent empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I translate the '^$' in python.

It's `grep -q -z '^$'` and in this context  with `dd bs=1 count=1` it just checks if the byte is a zero byte.

In python just check if the byte is equal to zero:

```
if byte == b'\x00':
```